# How to skip a set of PyTests in one skipif

Tags: pytest

Assume we have a test that can be executed several times (parameter as argument).
To enter the test it has to answer a certain condition, if correct test...
if not, skip to next test.
The problem, skipping amount is equivalent to `iterations` parameter.
How can I skip the whole set?

Code:

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(<condition>, reason='Not defined for testing')
@pytest.mark.parametrize('iteration', range(1, ITERATIONS + 1))
async def test_foo(self, iteration):
    pass

@pytest.mark.skipif(<condition>, reason='Not defined for testing')
@pytest.mark.parametrize('iteration', range(1, ITERATIONS + 1))
async def test_boo(self, iteration):
    pass
```

Result:

```
foo_1 - skipped
foo_2 - skipped
boo_1 - pass
boo_2 - pass
```

Expected:

```
foo_1 - skipped
boo_1 - pass // <---- no foo_2
boo_2 - pass
```

Comment: The parametrized tests are collected at load time, so they will each be skipped if parametrized this way.  You could hack something together that does the parametrization at run-time, in `pytest_generate_tests`, if the skip condition is a global one, but this would still need the skip marker to be added, which is somewhat awkward. I would leave the output as is and do some post-processing if needed.

Comment: The problem is not the output but the amount of time it takes to skip hundreds of iterations

Comment: The skip condition is global but dynamic. I mean that the variable in both tests are different for the skip condition. But I think it's not a problem, I could send it as an argument to pytest_generate_tests func, right?

Comment: You cannot send arguments to `pytest_generate_tests` , this is a predefined hook function. As a workaround, you could use different argument names and use these for the skip condition, but you still have to add the skip marker additionally to the tests - you cannot do this in `pytest_generate_tests`.

Answer (score 1):

The parametrized tests are collected at load time, so they will each be skipped if parametrized this way.

If you want to skip the test without it being parametrized, you have to do the parametrization at run-time, in `pytest_generate_tests`. As mentioned in the comments, you could make the skip condition dependend on the argument name as an (ugly) workaround, and you still have to add the skip condition to the tests themselves:

```py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'iteration1' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        params = [1] if <cond1> else range(1, ITERATIONS + 1)
        metafunc.parametrize('iteration', params)
    elif 'iteration2' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        params = [1] if <cond2> else range(1, ITERATIONS + 1)
        metafunc.parametrize('iteration', params)

@pytest.skipif(<cond1>, reason='Not defined for testing')
def test_foo(iteration1):
    pass


@pytest.skipif(<cond2>, reason='Not defined for testing')
def test_boo(iteration2):
    pass
```

Note that you cannot use `pytest.skip()` in `pytest_generate_tests`, as this would skip *all* tests.

If you don't care about the skip message, you could also just parametrize the skipped tests with an empty list, which would result in a skip message something like `got empty parameter set`, but would avoid evaluating the skip condition twice:

```py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'iteration1' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        params = [] if <cond1> else range(1, ITERATIONS + 1)
        metafunc.parametrize('iteration', params)
    elif 'iteration2' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        params = [] if <cond2> else range(1, ITERATIONS + 1)
        metafunc.parametrize('iteration', params)

def test_foo(iteration1):
    pass


def test_boo(iteration2):
    pass
```

Note that this is a hacky solutions, maybe someone else knows a better way to do this.